# Set equality using quantifiers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

In my lecture notes, I have the following equality which is unclear

$$
\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega), A) = 0 \} = \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}}\bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\left\{\omega : d(X_s(\omega), A)\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\}
$$

However, following the initial set I think it should be

$$
\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega), A) = 0 \} = \left\{\omega : \exists s\in [0,t], \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*},d(X_s(\omega), A)\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\} = \bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}}\left\{\omega : d(X_s(\omega), A)\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\}
$$

And clearly the sets are not the same since the one I get is more restrictive (one $s$ should satisfy the inequality for all $n\geq 1$ whereas for the other set there is no such restriction).

I would like to know if I am right and if not why please.

Thank you !

---

$\mathbb{N}^{*} = \mathbb{N}_{>0}$

To give more context, we consider $X_t$ as a continuous stochastic process and $A$ a closed set in some metric space and we want to prove that $\tau(\omega)=\inf\{t\geq 0 : X_t(\omega)\in A\}$ is a stopping time.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur The set of integer without $0$, I am French sorry if it is not a well known notation

Comment: Nothing to apologize over. I was just unfamiliar with it and thought maybe clarifying it will help you to get answers.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes I clarified this ! Thank you

Comment: @coboy I am French too; and no, $\mathbb N ^*$ for integers $\ge 1$ is generally not understood outside France, so it seems. By the way, half of the world defines $\mathbb N$ as integers $\ge 1$, so they don't need it. Note that "positive" and "negative" are also ambiguous. Some non-ambiguous notations I have seen on MSE: $\mathbb N _{>0}$, and $\mathbb N_{\ge 0}$ or $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Thank you for these remarks ! Added to the post the notation you shared it to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, they are probably the same in this context, for the following reason

$$\omega\in  \{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega), A) = 0 \} $$

Then it is also in

$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}}\bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\left\{\omega : d(X_s(\omega), A)\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\}$$

For the other direction, assume

$$\omega \in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}}\bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\left\{\omega : d(X_s(\omega), A)\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\} $$

This means that for any $n$ there is some $s_n\in[0,t]$ such that

$$d(X_{s_n}(\omega),A)<\frac{1}{n}$$

By the Bolzanno-Weierstrass theorem there is some convergent subsequence $(s_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to some $s_0$, since the stochastic process is continuous, one would expect that:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}d(X_{s_{n_k}}(\omega),A) = d(X_{s_0}(\omega),A)$$

(This you should verify, I am not familiar with the notation you use)

But this means

$$d(X_{s_0}(\omega),A)= 0$$

And also $s_0\in[0,t]$, so

$$\omega \in  \{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega), A) = 0 \} $$

Comment: You’re right thank you. I should investigate more. And your notation is correct for the subsequence of the stochastic process as far as I know !

Answer (score 1):

Since the context of the question is unclear, I suppose that for each $s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb Q$ $d(X_s(\omega),A)$ is some nonegative number, depending on $\omega$ (supposedly, some distance). Then

$$\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega), A) = 0 \} =$$
$$\bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{ \omega : d(X_s(\omega), A) = 0 \}=$$
$$\bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\left\{ \omega : d(X_s(\omega), A)\le \frac 1n\right\}.$$

which coincides with your formulation. But maybe the notes concern some special case when this set coincides with the set
$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\left\{ \omega : d(X_s(\omega), A)\le \frac 1n\right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry for the unclearness of my post, your guess was right.  To give some context it is to prove that a random variable is a stopping time, also something I added now in the post : the variable $X_t(\omega)$ is continuous with respect to t. However I do not see how it can play a role here..